# how to select the records in where clause with particular date

Tags: sql, ms-access

"SELECT * FROM FeeTrans where FeeTrans.rec_date  = #11/25/2016#"

i want to fetch the records with exact this date  but no records is coming 
i have tried "<>" symbols also but it fetches other date also

my rec date's data is in date/time(mm/dd/yyyy)

rec_date

1. 06/25/2016
2. 11/25/2016
3. 11/25/2016
4. 11/25/2016
5. 11/25/2016
6. 06/14/2016
7. 11/25/2016

Thank you

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: With datetime you may need datevalue, also year,month,day is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your recorded dates contain time as well. Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM FeeTrans WHERE Fix(FeeTrans.rec_date) = #11/25/2016#"
```

Or (faster if many records):

```
"SELECT * FROM FeeTrans WHERE FeeTrans.rec_date Between #11/25/2016# And #11/25/2016 23:59:59#"
```